# SQLAlchemy - subquery in a SELECT clause

Tags: sqlalchemy

I would like to know the best way to achieve the subquery in SELECT clause using SQLAlchemy

Here is my database table.

```
mysql> select * from feedback_question;
+----+---------------------+-------------+--------------+
| id | created             | question_id | feedbacktype |
+----+---------------------+-------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2022-03-31 09:53:14 |         488 |            1 |
|  2 | 2022-03-31 09:53:21 |         508 |            1 |
|  3 | 2022-03-31 09:53:27 |         607 |            2 |
|  4 | 2022-03-31 09:53:31 |         606 |            1 |
|  5 | 2022-03-31 09:53:33 |         608 |            2 |
|  6 | 2022-03-31 09:55:30 |         608 |            2 |
|  7 | 2022-03-31 09:55:33 |         606 |            1 |
|  8 | 2022-03-31 09:55:40 |         607 |            1 |
|  9 | 2022-03-31 09:58:40 |         607 |            2 |
| 10 | 2022-03-31 09:59:04 |         607 |            2 |
+----+---------------------+-------------+--------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the actual query that I would like to define using SQLAlchemy.

```
mysql> select T.question_id, 
              T.feedbacktype, 
              count(T.feedbacktype) AS "count", 
              round( count(T.feedbacktype) * 100 / 
                         (select count(U.feedbacktype) from feedback_question as U where U.question_id=T.question_id)
              ) AS "countpercent" 
        from feedback_question as T   group by question_id, feedbacktype;
+-------------+--------------+-------+--------------+
| question_id | feedbacktype | count | countpercent |
+-------------+--------------+-------+--------------+
|         488 |            1 |     1 |          100 |
|         508 |            1 |     1 |          100 |
|         606 |            1 |     2 |          100 |
|         607 |            1 |     1 |           25 |
|         607 |            2 |     3 |           75 |
|         608 |            2 |     2 |          100 |
+-------------+--------------+-------+--------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is how my current statement looks like:

```
dbsession.query( cls.question_id, cls.feedbacktype, func.count(cls.feedbacktype).label("count"), XXXXXXXXXX.label("countpercent") ).filter(cls.question_id.in_(question_ids)).group_by(cls.question_id, cls.feedbacktype).all()
```

I am using  SQLAlchemy 1.4 and MySQL 5.7

I reviewed the SQLAlchemy documentation about subqueries and scalars, but I am not sure how to apply them in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use [scalar_subquery](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.scalar_subquery) and [aliased](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=aliased#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased).  This example is using postgresql but mysql should work.  The output is not ordered as it is in your example.  There is even more information in the [correlated subquery section](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/glossary.html#term-correlated-subquery).

#### code

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    DateTime
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session, aliased


Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=False)


class FeedbackQuestion(Base):
    __tablename__ = "feedback_question"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime)
    question_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    feedbacktype = Column(Integer, nullable=False)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def extract(line):
    id, created_at, question_id, feedbacktype = line.split('|')[1:-1]
    return dict(id=id, created_at=created_at, question_id=question_id, feedbacktype=feedbacktype)

lines = [extract(line) for line in """|  1 | 2022-03-31 09:53:14 |         488 |            1 |
|  2 | 2022-03-31 09:53:21 |         508 |            1 |
|  3 | 2022-03-31 09:53:27 |         607 |            2 |
|  4 | 2022-03-31 09:53:31 |         606 |            1 |
|  5 | 2022-03-31 09:53:33 |         608 |            2 |
|  6 | 2022-03-31 09:55:30 |         608 |            2 |
|  7 | 2022-03-31 09:55:33 |         606 |            1 |
|  8 | 2022-03-31 09:55:40 |         607 |            1 |
|  9 | 2022-03-31 09:58:40 |         607 |            2 |
| 10 | 2022-03-31 09:59:04 |         607 |            2 |
""".splitlines() if line.strip()]


with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    session.add_all([FeedbackQuestion(**line) for line in lines])


with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    T = aliased(FeedbackQuestion, name="T")
    U = aliased(FeedbackQuestion, name="U")
    denom = select(func.count(U.feedbacktype)).where(U.question_id == T.question_id).scalar_subquery()
    q = select(T.question_id, T.feedbacktype, func.count(T.feedbacktype).label("count"), func.round((func.count(T.feedbacktype) * 100) / denom).label("countpercent")).group_by(T.question_id, T.feedbacktype)
    print (q)
    for result in session.execute(q):
        print(result)
```

#### query

```sql
SELECT "T".question_id, "T".feedbacktype, count("T".feedbacktype) AS count, round((count("T".feedbacktype) * :count_1) / (SELECT count("U".feedbacktype) AS count_2 
FROM feedback_question AS "U" 
WHERE "U".question_id = "T".question_id)) AS countpercent 
FROM feedback_question AS "T" GROUP BY "T".question_id, "T".feedbacktype
```

#### output

```py
(606, 1, 2, 100.0)
(608, 2, 2, 100.0)
(488, 1, 1, 100.0)
(607, 1, 1, 25.0)
(607, 2, 3, 75.0)
(508, 1, 1, 100.0)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked exactly as I wanted.